# How to render patial through replaceWith()

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, replacewith

I have looked at similar question and the answers didn't work and may be dated. I think there used to be a thing called RJS to do this but, I am trying to simply remove one partial and replace another.

```
$("#me")
  .replaceWith( '<%= escape_javascript render(partial: "photoSpread") %>')
```

What happens is the its sent to the browser as text and just displays
 **<%= escape_javascript render(partial: "photoSpread") %>**

Answer (score 2):

Replace **`<%`** with **`<%=`**

```
$("#me").replaceWith('<%= escape_javascript render("photoSpread") %>')
```

- **`<%`** will just evaluate the ruby code inside it

whereas

- **`<%=`** will evaluate and print the code inside `<%= %>`

Comment: I corrected that in my code. However I still have the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

sorry I wasn't thinking. rails is servver side so I have to load all the partials first and then swap. Something like this.

```
  jQuery ->
  $("#me2").hide()
  $("#go").on "click", ->
    $("#me").toggle()
    $("#me2").toggle()
```